# Glassfish with Mojarra 2.2 and EJB: Injection Fail (NullPointerException)

Tags: glassfish, ejb, jsf-2.2, mojarra

i have a normal dynamic web project with a Glassfish 3 server. 
I have a managed-bean that injects a stateless bean. 
With Mojarra 2.1.6 all works fine.

But when i add javax.faces-2.2.7.jar (Mojarra) to my Web-Inf lib folder and try to access to my site i get an Nullpointerexception for my "service".

The deploy and the new mojarra version is successful accepted.

**EXCEPTION:** java.lang.NullPointerException
    at bean.MyBean.init(MyBean.java:18)

Example Code:

Managed- Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {
@EJB
private MyStatelessBean statelessBean;

private String hello;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    setHello(statelessBean.sayHello());
}

public String getHello() {
    return hello;
}

public void setHello(String hello) {
    this.hello = hello;
}
}
```

Stateless- Bean:

```
@Stateless
public class MyStatelessBean {

public String sayHello(){
    return "Hello";
}
}
```

XHTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.hello}" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Only putting JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` isn't right. More things need to be done. See the dupe.

Comment: yes, make this all (See this Thread before). Without EJB the new Mojarra works fine. Only EJB doesnt work.

Comment: Please edit the question to include this information about `glassfish-web.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was reset glassfish cache and all works fine ;)